# firebase 8.4 runs .once() repeatedly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My applications runs well in firebase@8.3.3. On 8.4.0/1/2/3, the .once() code is executed repeatedly, indefinitely.

my code:

```
public buStateClick(key: string, action: state) {
    this._afDB.database.ref(`${path}/${key}/state`).once('value', (snap) => {
      this._afDB.database.ref(`${path}/${key}/state`).off(); // required after 8.4.0
      if (snap.exists()) {
        this._afDB.database.ref(`${path}/${key}`).update({state: newState});
      }
    });
}
```

In my original program without the .off(), when the code runs, the .once() and .update() were executed >700 times until the stack fails. Adding .off() reverts it back to its original behaviour.

I believe that .once() is supposed to .off() itself, and should never run more than once. There is no reason the code needs an .off() to work.

reference: my original question
[firebase 8.4 makes my .once() keep firing [was: firebase 8.4 makes my onclick event keep firing]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67343812/firebase-8-4-makes-my-once-keep-firing-was-firebase-8-4-makes-my-onclick-ev)

@NickArmitage has a similar problem but his code only works up to 8.3.2.

Comment: There seems to have been a bug in SDK release 8.4.0, that lead to a very quick follow up release of 8.4.1, so you might want to upgrade to see if that fixes the problem: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_841_-_april_13_2021

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen as I indicated, the problem persists in 841 842 and 843.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this problem here: https://jsbin.com/xofinop/4/edit?html,js,console. At first glance that indeed looks like a regression, so I'm checking with the team to see what might have happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

This is indeed a regression in the 8.4 version of the SDK. Thanks for the clear MCVE, which I was able to reproduce with the JSBin that I linked in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354459/firebase-8-4-runs-once-repeatedly/67391979#comment119092681_67354459).

The bug was also recorded on the Github repo for the SDK, and a fix is in the works. Keep an eye out on the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/4864) to catch any updates.

Comment: Yes, shipped in 8.6.1